# UI Router stateParams not updating in child routes

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I had a route with a param working but then added some child routes and now it will not update.

**Event Template**

```
<a ui-sref="event.detail({id: event.id})" ng-repeat="event in events">
    Event {{event.id}}
</a>
```

**UI Router**

```
.state('event', {
    url: '/event',
    views: {
        'event': {
            template: ..., // shown above
            controller: 'Event'
        }
    }
})
.state('event.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        'event-detail': {
            template: ...,
            controller: 'EventDetail' // shows a single event
        }
    }
})
// tabs to switch between the different details
.state('event.detail.info', {
    url: '/info',
    views: {
        'event-info': {
            template: ...
        }
    }
})
.state('event.detail.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
        'event-map': {
            template: ...
        }
    }
})
.state('event.detail.chat', {
    url: '/chat',
    views: {
        'event-chat': {
            template: ...
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller**

```
function EventDetail($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.getEventDetails = getEventDetails;

    $scope.getEventDetails($stateParams.id);

    function getEventDetails(id) {
        console.log(id); // returns correct first time, then nothing. Used to work every time!
        ...
    }
}
```

Run through of what's going wrong:

- click on `Event 1`
- url changes to `event/1` and gets the right event details
- go back to list and click on `Event 2`
- url changes to `event/2` but displays details for event 1
- click on the info, map or chat tab and the url changes from `event/2` to `event/1/info`, `event/1/map` and `event/1/chat`

Comment: What does `event` state do ? Does is show anything ?

Comment: Yep, the template in the question is rendered by the Event state. It shows a list of all Events.

Comment: I think this is whats happening, ambigious routes. Url : `event/detail/info` passes through `event/detail/:id` as well as `event/detail/info`. Therefore its ambiguous.

Comment: But I don't have a route for `event/detail/anything` should it not just be `event/:id` and `event/:id/info` from what I have above? How would I make it unambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to user `cache: false` in the `event.detail` states and it's child states.